# How to fix 'cordova installation on windows' error in ionic

Tags: ionic4

PS E:\Ionic> npm install -g ionic cordova
npm ERR! path C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\cordova-c1f99104\node_modules@angular\cli
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\cordova-c1f99104\node_modules@angular\cli' -> 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging@angular\cli-4806b926'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-06-03T09_30_15_495Z-debug.log
PS E:\Ionic> npm install -g cordova
npm ERR! path C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\cordova-c1f99104\node_modules@angular\cli
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\cordova-c1f99104\node_modules@angular\cli' -> 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging@angular\cli-4806b926'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-06-03T09_39_33_294Z-debug.log
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`npm cache clean`

followed by

`npm install -g cordova`